# Python Pandas: Input Authorized Excel File into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, authentication, web, xlsb

I am trying to get data from .xlsb file in an authorized website. But it comes out with error message: 'HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized'. What should I do to authorize so that the data comes out in pandas table in Python? Here the code that I tried so far:

```
supplier_list_xlsb = pd.read_excel('https://..../3026744.xlsb', sheet_name = 'xxxxxx',engine = 'pyxlsb')
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser's cache may be that will help resolve this issue.Are you sure website is authorized to access?

Comment: Yes Rav. I already log in the website via browser but it seems not working when I try to extract using python code.

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer. I need to use NTLM authentication (instead of basic) to download the file and use the downloaded file into Pandas to get the table. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm3 import HttpNtlmAuth

auth=HttpNtlmAuth('username','password')
myfile = requests.get("https://..../3026744.xlsb", auth=auth)

open('C:/Users/Desktop/test/Supplier.xlsb', 'wb').write(myfile.content)

supplier_list_xlsb = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/test/Supplier.xlsb', sheet_name = 'xxxxxx',engine = 'pyxlsb')
```